# How to remove empty duplicate lines with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a legacy program running on RH5 that generates output in text files that are then printed using lp/lpd.

The requirement is to remove repeated blank lines. i.e. if there are 2 or more empty lines, they should be replaced by a single blank line.

However, the empty lines have varying space characters:

```
......Heading.......
....................
...Name:.John.Doe...
...PIN:.......123...
....................   <--- This should be replaced with a single blank line
....................
...Date:.02/03/2019.
```

If I remove repeated spaces, that would effect the formatting. So, lines with all spaces only should be removed.

Comment: Did you try `uniq` command?

Comment: No. The printout have lines with dashes which they want printed. uniq would have removed consecutive dash line.

Comment: @F.Hauri et al: Kindly let me know why the question was marked as you did. I don't see it as broad or with multiple question, but if I'm mistaken, do let me know so that I can correct future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along:

```
sed 'N;/^ *\n *$/!P;D'
```

Small explanation:

- `N` - add next line to pattern space
- `/^ *\n *$/` - we have two lines in pattern space, if they are empty, there will only be newline with spaces. So match from beginning `^` of the pattern, `*` match zero or more spaces only a newline, a newline `\n`, then `*` zero or more space till the end of pattern space `$`
- `!` - if the regex does not match
- `P` - print the pattern space up until the newline
- `D` - delete the pattern space up until newline and start over

Tested with:

```
$ printf "   %s   \n" "A" "" "" "" "B" "C" "D" "" "" "" "" "E" | sed 'N;/^ *\n *$/!P;D'
   A   

   B   
   C   
   D   

   E
```

I see the last line is not printed with my GNU sed with `--posix`, I was able to fix it with `$q` on the end, I guess what `N` does differs between posix and gnu sed (it does not print pattern space in posix):

```
sed --posix '$q;N;/^ *\n *$/!P;D;'
```

Comment: Thank you. My last try using `cat myfile |sed -e 'N;/^ *\n *$/d;P;D'` was close but not quite there. I'll use your solution.

Comment: It's because the `d` deletes it all, so multiple empty lines would not work. The `N;/^ *\n *$/D;P;D` was my first answer. Then I saw that the `D;P;D` can be just shortened to this `!P;D`.

Answer (score -2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne '$empty = ! /\S/;
          print unless $empty && $previous_empty;
          $previous_empty = $empty;
         ' -- file.txt
```

- `-n` reads the file line by line
- `/\S/` matches any non-space
- `!` means "not", i.e. the variable `$empty` is set to true when there's nothing but whitespace
- the line is printed unless it's empty and the previous line was also empty
- the emptiness of the previous line is handled by keeping the emptiness of the current line in a different variable.

You can even use the `-i.bak` option to change the file in place.